# MySQL big chunks of data - fast access without recalculation

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

I would like to store big chunks of data in RAM using sphinx /solr/ elastic search whatever else suits such needs (The problem is I don't know what  tool suits the best I had only heard that people use them).

I build reports about sales, I get nearly 800-900k lines of  sales per month  and user wants to scroll the page and see them smoothly.

I can't give them all data at once  becasue browser will just hang
 in the same time I can't use LIMIT from mysql because queries demand merging cross tables.

Recalculating it on the flow is not an option.

Creating a temp table in mysql is a bad idea because there are a bunch of criteria and  more than one user can view data.

```
 Temporary_table
id   product_id product_count order_id order_status.... .....user_id
```

Having such table I would store all result for current user in the table and would hold them there as long as user doesn't make a new query. But I don't like this solution. There must be something better.
I feel like it's over my head.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you partitioned your sales data?

Comment: How many characters are we talking about? Is in-memory caching a reasonable thing to do or is it just too big?

Comment: I've 8GB of RAM,  I'm sure it would  take no more than 1 GB of raw data at most. But they must be kept sorted and indexes (like in mysql). Otherwise it's not sane idea to sort them again every time

Comment: This is a problem of "managing user expectations".  Scrolling through a million lines is _awful_.  Neither they nor you is thinking enough out of the box to think of a better way to visualize the information.  Focus on that, then come back to us.

Answer (score 0):

"Drill down", don't "Scroll down" !

When I need to present a million lines of info, I start by thinking of way to slice and dice it -- subtotals by hour, by region, by product type, by whatever.  Each slice might be a hundred lines -- quite manageable, especially with summary tables.

In that hundred lines would be clickable items that take the user to a more detailed page about one of the items.  That would also have a hundred lines (or 10 or 1000 -- whatever makes sense; but >1000 is usually unreasonable).  That page may have further links to drill further down.  And/or links to move laterally.

With suitable slicing and dicing, you are very unlikely to need to send him a million lines; only a few hundred.

With suitable Summary Tables, the "tmp tables", etc, go away.